# Enable js to redirect to a private folder of apache server

Tags: javascript, php, apache, .htaccess

Let's say i have a public php folder like this :

> root/thepublicphpfolder

and here is the private folder inside the public  where i put some php scripts that user should not have direct access

> root/thepublicphpfolder/privatefolder

I have successfully configure to make private folder only accessible by the application , but i can't find a way to access this folder from my script code(jquery). Do i have to make some configuration on my .htaccess file to enable jquery access my private folder or there is no way to do that ?

Comment: You can not do such a thing, client side scripts (javascript/jquery etc.) are treated as it was user accessing them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since jQuery / Javascript is run in the context of the browser allowing access would effectively require allowing public access to your private folder.

What you should consider is adding an authentication layer to prevent unauthenticated access. Your PHP files would still be publicly accessible but would require authentication to perform any action. Depending on your project's requirements I would recommend taking a look at [PHP sessions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php) or some sort of [OAuth flow](https://github.com/bshaffer/oauth2-server-php).

Comment: Thank you you for your quick reply!Well, i have not seen any of the "big" sites to require authentication access for any files. In my case, i have 2 dropdowns that are populated from my database and the choice of the first , populates accordingly the second one.As you understand, i use a php script file for accessing my database,which should not be accessible.So asking for authentication is the only solution to my problem?

Comment: @ThemisBeris, it totally depends on your requirements. If you don't mind that any user could publicly retrieve that information, don't worry about it. If it needs to stay private, than make sure the user has a valid, authenticated session (based on username/password, OAuth, etc.) before returning the data.

Comment: Thank you very much! I think i will go for OAuth :)